# Local IIS hangs after VS.NET build

Tags: visual-studio-2008, iis, web-applications

I have an ASP.NET web application that occasionally hangs after I build it.  It is intermittent and there is no pattern to this.  When I try to access it afterwards, IE just waits for IIS to respond, which it doesn't do, unless I restart IIS.

This is on my local machine, running Vista Ultimate x64, VS 2008, 1 web application, 8 additional class libraries.

**--UPDATE--**

In the System log, there's an entry for each time it's happened:

> A worker process '8068' serving
>   application pool 'MyCustomAppPool'
>   failed to stop a listener channel for
>   protocol 'http' in the allotted time. 
>   The data field contains the error
>   number.

Event ID:5138 http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc734995.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I have finally found a suitable answer.

Tess Ferrandez's post on hangs when loading the ASP.NET assemblies could be the problem:

http://blogs.msdn.com/tess/archive/2009/09/22/asp-net-case-study-hang-when-loading-assemblies.aspx

Sounds like the GC is getting confused and getting hung up.

Answer (score 0):

Check the Windows Event Log to see what's wrong with your ASP.net worker process (might be having problems loading DLLs while the build isn't quite complete and rapid failures are causing the worker process to stop).

Comment: No entries in the Event Log when the application is compiled/recompiled

Answer (score 0):

You could try putting some logging in the Application_Start, Application_Stop, Session_Start and Session_End events, to check if the web application is actually being hit.

Comment: The web application is not being hit.  The problem exists when IIS is restarted when the application is compiled/recompiled

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a long shot, but if you have an antivirus software installed, try to disable its web checking feature. (If it has one.)

Comment: No anti-virus software installed

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have all of the available updates applied to your machine; including SP1.

Comment: All service packs have been installed